# struct Time property doesn't load from Go sqlx library

Tags: go, sqlite, sqlx

I have a struct with a property time:

```
type Basket struct {  
  ...  
  Created_at time.Time `db:"created_at"`
}
```

with the time saved as:

```
basket.Created_at = time.Now().UTC()
```

If I save it using Insert sql statement, it saves the time nicely in the SQLite3 but when I select the desired record using:

```
ret_basket := Basket{}
err := database.DB.Get(&ret_basket, "SELECT id, ..., created_at FROM baskets WHERE user_id = ?", some_user_id)
```

It returns the record with other properties loaded properly except the time property which is `ret_basket.Created_at` as `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no official package for Sqlite so I assume you are using https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 Probably your issue is result of wrong `created_at` field declaration in database which should be `DATETIME` because the next code works perfectly on my machine (I've removed all error checks):

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
    "log"
    "time"
)

type Post struct {
    Id      int64     `db:"post_id"`
    Created time.Time `db:"created"`
}

func main() {
    db, _ := sqlx.Connect("sqlite3", "post_db.db")
    db.MustExec("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS posts; CREATE TABLE posts (post_id INT, created DATETIME);")

    p1 := Post{Id: 1, Created: time.Now().UTC()}
    p2 := Post{}

    tx := db.MustBegin()
    tx.NamedExec("INSERT INTO posts (post_id, created) VALUES (:post_id, :created)", &p1)
    tx.Commit()

    db.Get(&p2, "SELECT post_id, created FROM posts WHERE post_id = $1", p1.Id)
    log.Println(p2.Created.Format("2006-01-02"))
}
```